# Sending Email VB.net Exception

Tags: vb.net, email, smtpclient

this is my code it was running without errors but suddenly
an exception  appears
The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

```
Dim smtpserver As New SmtpClient()
    Dim mail As New MailMessage()
    smtpserver.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@gmail.com", "mypass")
    smtpserver.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    smtpserver.Port = "587"
    mail = New MailMessage
    mail.From = New MailAddress("myHouseHQ@gmail.com")
    mail.To.Add(Form2.TextBox1.Text)
    mail.Subject = "EagleEyes"
    mail.Body = "EagleEyes has detected a movement!"
    If emailphoto Then
        Dim attach As New Attachment("D:\hi" & sm & ".jpg")
        mail.Attachments.Add(attach)
    End If
    smtpserver.EnableSsl = True

    smtpserver.UseDefaultCredentials = False

    '   Try1
    smtpserver.Send(mail)
    'Catch ex As SmtpException
    'MsgBox("Error Connection!" & ex.Message)

    'End Try
    sm += 1
```

Comment: Have you tried reading the exception message? Your credentials are obviously incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "" by the port.

Please try this for the port:

```
smtpserver.Port = 587
```